# What to do when Finder just won't quit / relaunch likely due to network share issues on client?

Tags: finder, macos, high-sierra, smb

Been having more and more trouble with `Finder` and filesystem access on 10.12 and 10.13.  It seems that when SMB mounts are involved, the system sometimes comes to a creeping halt.

Usually `Finder` seems to be at the center stage when this happens and when I try to kill it (`kill -9`) or Relaunch it from `Dock`, it still doesn't respond.  It's windows go away, but the process never really dies and respawns.

Once this happens other processes seem to cascade into failure as well. For example, Terminal will not respond when attempting to `ls` a smb mount in `/Volumes/` after this and hangs just like Finder without even control-c killing `ls`.

I suspect there are IO errors with SMB for some reason or another, but I can't be sure. Other workstations are fine when accessing the same host.  It's an enormous enigma and the only resolution so far has been restarting the workstations that exhibit this problem.  Restarting is just not a viable solution when you're in the middle of work and so I need to hunt down the root issue...

Any thoughts on hunting down what may be at fault or how to give `Finder` a stiffer kick in the butt than `kill[all] -9`?